# Value.match() Regex in Google Refine

Tags: regex, openrefine

I am trying to extract a sequence of numbers from a column in Google Refine.  Here is my code  for doing it:

```
value.match(/[\d]+/)[0]
```

The data in my column is in the format of

```
abcababcabc 1234566 abcabcbacdf
```

The results is "null".  I have no idea why!! It is also null if instead of `\d` I try `\w`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenRefine doesn't add implicit wildcards to the end of the pattern as some systems do (and as one might expect).  Try this pattern instead:

```
value.match(/.*?(\d+).*?/)[0]
```

You need the lazy/non-greedy qualifier (ie question mark) on the wildcards so that they don't gobble up some of your digits too.  If you just use `/.*(\d+).*/` you'll only match a single digit because the rest of them will be taken by the .* pattern.

Full documentation for the implementation can be seen in Java's [`Pattern` class docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Hi Tom - Thanks for your answer.  I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting a NULL

Comment: I thought perhaps it was because I was using the development version, but I just went back and cut-and-paste the exact data and regex from this page into Refine 2.5 and got 1234566 so I'm not really sure what to suggest.

Comment: It actually works now - I was trying it on an input which is slightly different.  Can you explain / parse what your regex means?  What is the lazy/non-greedy qualifier? 

Also the documentation I am reading doesn't seem to help (https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Understanding-Regular-Expressions).  Is there another reference that explains regex in Open Refine?

Thank you!

Comment: It uses Java's regex implementation, so the Pattern class contains the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html I've updated my answer with more explanation.