# Openrefine, match text inside parentheses

Tags: regex, openrefine

I'm having cells like

```
10 (1880 15) ; 11 (1880 15) ; 12 (1880 15) ; 7 (1880 15) ; 3 (1880 15) ; 9 (1880 15) ; 2 (1880 15) ; 1 (1880 15) ; 4 (1880 15) ; 5 (1880 15) ; 6 (1880 15) ; 8 (1880 15)
```

and I want to take all the text inside the parentheses. Using this expression it gives me a Null result:

```
value.match(/\(.*?\)/)
```

Why that?
Thanks

Comment: How does the `match` API work?  Does it repeatedly check for a pattern, does it check for the first match, or something else?

Comment: They see `match(/.../)` and suddenly think about JS.

Comment: `value.match(/\(([^()]*)\)/` gives always Null.
I don't really understand the work of `match`: I found that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896772/value-match-regex-in-google-refine but I think it doesn't work with my case.

Comment: Just for the record, [here is the documentation of this function](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#matchstring-s-regexp-p).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `match` function [does not work as you think](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1296). It is very counter-intuitive. That's why since Open Refine 3 there is a `find` function that does exactly what you want.

```
value.find(/\(.*?\)/)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know the `find` function. Thanks

Comment: Sorry another question: if I want to put in the column all the results, not only the first or else of the list, what can I use?

Comment: You can use `join` to transform your array into a string. Ex: `value.find(/\(.*?\)/).join(',')`